# How Refresh a list after push? AngularJS/ DB

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, refresh

**Hi Sir,**
I would know how i can refresh my List after add , edit or delete operation with AngularJS .

i Post my Controller And my HTML code ,  it work but i must refresh all page for see the changes in DB. Ty for all request.

CONTROLLER:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('controllerFilm', function(service , $scope ) {

var vm = this;

vm.allFilm = function() {
    service.allFilm().then(
    function(data){//success
        vm.allFilm = data; // accounts list
    },function(err){//error
          console.log("errore di chiamata allFilm");
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="controllerFilm as cf">
<button class="button" ng-click="cf.allFilm()">FILM MANAGER</button>
 <br>
 <br>
    <div class="scroll"> 
     <table class="blueTable">  
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>TITLE</th>
                <th>RELASE YEAR</th>
                <th>LENGTH</th>
                <th>EDIT</th>
                <th>DELETE</th>     
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr ng-repeat =
                "film in cf.allFilm  | orderBy : '-filmId' | limitTo : 10">
                    <th>{{film.filmId}}</th>
                    <th>{{film.title}}</th>
                    <th>{{film.relaseYear}}</th>
                    <th>{{film.length}}</th>
                    <th align="center"> <button  
                         ng-click="cf.editFilm(film)">EDIT</button></th>
                    <th align="center"> <button  
                         ng-click="cf.deleteFilm(film)">DELETE</button></th>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

PS : i don't post my function edit and delete..

Answer (score 0):

Although changes should automatically be applied as AngularJs has two way binding but sometimes, it does cause this issue. try calling below scope method after setting data to the list.

```
$scope.$apply();
```

P.S: This is a way of forcefully executing digest cycle to reflect changes right away.

Comment: thancks ,  i try .